# Reading past a buffer in C while using FGets

Tags: c, fgets

I am faced with a bit of a problem that I need assistance on particularly

In my program

The user can enter text through stdin in this format ONLY

lunch XYZ

Where "lunch" is  a string of 5 and X is a upper character from A to T and Y is a integer from 0 to 9 and Z is also an intger from 0 to 9

Valid input consists of

```
lunch A10
lunch B5
lunch C7
lunch A10
```

Now the maximum user input length is 9, which is lunch XXX (where there is 1 whitespace)
The minimum valid input is lunch A1 (which is 8 characters long including space)

Now my code sets the input buffer to 11, to account for extra characters the user puts in by accident

If there is extra characters the user will get "Invalid!" to standard output

for example

`lunch asdasdasd` is invalid

`lunch asdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd` is also invalid

`lunch \n asdasdasdasdasd A21` is also invalid

**my problem**

My problem is that my fgets ignores any characters after the 11th character

Now if the user inputs something like

`lunch "asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd" A10` -> should print "Invalid"

My code does nothing, it should print "Invalid!"

How can I, safely read past my buffer length of 11 and handle much larger inputs the user can accidentally enter, and return a error message

```
char Buffer[11];

int main() {
    while(fgets(Buffer,11,stdin) != NULL){
        int valid_command_entered = 0;

        if (Buffer[strlen(Buffer) - 1] == '\n') {
            Buffer[strlen(Buffer) - 1] = '\0'; // Remove newline
        } else {
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {} // Clear input buffer
        }

        if (strlen(Buffer) > 10) {
            printf("Invalid!\n");
            valid_command_entered = 0;
            continue;
        }


        if(strstr(Buffer,"lunch") != NULL && strlen(Buffer) < 11){
            lunch(Buffer);
            valid_command_entered = 1;
            fflush(stdin);
        }

        if(valid_command_entered == 0)
        {
            printf("Invalid!\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int lunch(const char buffer[]){
    if(buffer[0] != 'l' && count_spaces() >=1){
        printf("Invalid!\n");
    }else if(count_spaces() > 1){
        printf("Invalid!\n");
    }else if(strlen(buffer) >= 8 && strlen(buffer) <= 10 && !strncmp(buffer, "lunchment ", 10)) {
        printf("Invalid!\n");
        fflush(stdin);
    }else if(strcmp("lunch ",buffer) == 0){
        printf("Invalid!\n");
    }else if(strcmp("lunch",buffer) == 0){
        printf("Invalid!\n");
    }
    else if(count_spaces() == 0){
        printf("Invalid!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int count_spaces(){
    int size = sizeof(Buffer);
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; ++i){
        if(Buffer[i] == ' '){
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**my code can handle**

Trailing and leading spaces but not input larger than 11 (in fact the input will be much greater than 11 and I am excepted to safely read past the buffer).

Comment: Point 1: don't use such a tiny buffer. Use one large enough to take the whole line, such as `char Buffer[1000];`. You won't have to mess around clearing false input, and note that `fflush(stdin)` is *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 1):

First: Your program has undefined behavior because it uses implicit declarations of `lunch` and `count_spaces`. Either forward declare them, or put the functions in the opposite order.

The longest valid string is `9` characters long, but your test for validity accepts strings that are `10` characters long, so change the condition to:

```c
if (strstr(Buffer, "lunch") != NULL && strlen(Buffer) < 10) {
//                                                      ^^
```

> how can I, safely read past my buffer length of 11

You already have the code for that:

```c
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}  // Clear input buffer
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n5nPc9Tj3)